# Keras CNN training accuracy is good but test accuracy is very low

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

Please give me any comment for these CNN results.
I have used 2000 training images and 400 test images.
Training accuracy is perfect but test accuracy is very low. 
I think it because there is much variation between training and test images.
Anyone have a good idea for this case?

[[image: Accuracy plot]]

Comment: Would probably fit stats.stackexchange more

Answer (score 6):

This is clear case of over-fitting. How many learneable parameters you have? For example VGGnet has 138M parameters and in this case its not very hard to see some neuron in the network must have sort of memorized a training image as it is and thus your network is not generalizing well.

<s>To fix that, first of all you can try a simpler model if task is simple like discriminating between shapes</s>. Also you can increase training data via transformations like swapping color channels (if it doesnt impact the output class), flipping or rotating image to make your net generalize better. Include L1/L2 regularization in your loss function and try dropouts.

Comment: Fully agree with overfitting, disagree with "simpler model". You need regularization techniques, such as the transformations that you suggested and L1/L2. Other techniques are dropout and early stopping (edit : I see you added dropouts, for me it yielded the best results)

Comment: I did some study and yes you are right, a shallower model is more susceptible to 'memorization' than a deeper network which can utilize hierarchy from data. The benefit from a smaller network is improved training time only I believe. Thanx for pointing out.  I am editing answer suitably